# Run function only on index.html page (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a function that runs a random word generator on my index.html page, it works just fine however it continues to run when you're on any other page as well (because of windows.onload).

I am unsure how to write javascript to say "only run this function on index.html, no other page" or "just on this class"

```js
window.onload = function refreshWord()
  setInterval(function randomWord() {
    const words = ['Engineer', 'Developer', 'Illustrator', 'Cyclist', 'Artist'];
    const randomGenerator = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
    document.getElementById('textswap').innerHTML = words[randomGenerator];
  }, 2000);
```

```html
        <div class="col">
          <h4>These are the words, a <span class="front-page-text-swap" id="textswap"> person </span>.</h4>
        </div>
```

My end goal is to have the function `refreshWord()` execute only on the index.html page and no other however I'm at a loss at how to do that (and I'd like to use vanilla js, not jQuery)

Comment: Why not just use at least some separate Javascript for the index.html page and then put the `windows.onload = function() {...}` only in the Javascript for that page?  There is no rule that one must have all the same Javascript on all your pages.

Comment: @jfriend00 I've never thought of that, thank you!

Comment: I added that idea and another one to an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check to see if the `pathname` is `index.html`, and if it is, create the interval:

```
if (window.location.pathname === '/index.html') {
  setInterval( ...
}
```

It would also be nice to only select `textswap` *once*, rather than every time the interval runs, and to only create *one* `words` array, rather than declare a new array every time:

```
if (window.location.pathname === '/index.html') {
  const words = ['Engineer', 'Developer', 'Illustrator', 'Cyclist', 'Artist'];
  const getRandomWord = () => words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
  const textswap = document.getElementById('textswap');
  setInterval(() => {
    textswap.textContent = getRandomWord();
  });
}
```

Comment: this worked great! however for some reason now it's not working mobile

Answer (score 0):

You can take the code that you only want in `index.html` and take it out of your shared Javascript page that all your pages share and put it in a `<script>` tag that is only in the HTML of the `index.html` page, not in any other pages:

```
<script>
// insert this script only in the index.html page and 
// directly inserted, not via a separate script file
window.onload = function refreshWord()
  setInterval(function randomWord() {
    const words = ['Engineer', 'Developer', 'Illustrator', 'Cyclist', 'Artist'];
    const randomGenerator = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
    document.getElementById('textswap').innerHTML = words[randomGenerator];
  }, 2000);
</script>
```

You can also test for a page element that only exists on `index.html`.  So, if the `textswap` element only exists on `index.html`, then you could do this:

```
window.onload = function refreshWord()
  var textswap = document.getElementById('textswap');
  // see if the textswap element exists in this page
  if (textswap) {
      setInterval(function randomWord() {
        const words = ['Engineer', 'Developer', 'Illustrator', 'Cyclist', 'Artist'];
        const randomGenerator = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
        textswap.innerHTML = words[randomGenerator];
      }, 2000);
  }
```

So, that the `setInterval()` is only called if some element which is unique to the target page is actually present.

This "content-detection" is sometimes safer than URL testing because it tracks the actual page you want rather than a URL (which could be changed at some point).